# symfony doctrine cannot commit one transaction in for loop

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, transactions, doctrine

I have a problem with this code :

```
foreach($commandes as $commande)
  $conn = $this->em->getConnection();
  $conn->beginTransaction();
  $conn->setAutoCommit(false);

  try {
    $tmp = $this->checkCommande($commande); // in this function there is multiple relationship created and pushed 

    if ($tmp) {
        $result = $tmp['result'];
        if ('OK' === $result) {
            $commande->setCompleted(true);
            $this->em->flush();
            $conn->commit();
        }
    }
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    $conn->rollBack();
    throw $e;
  }
}
```

If I have multiple commands and if one is not committed then all are not committed.

Answer (score 0):

You have set a condition such that commands can only be committed if `'OK' === $result`. If this condition is not met, an exception is thrown and the changes are rolled back. To fix this issue, you should move the `$conn->commit()` call outside of this condition, those changes are always committed unless an exception is thrown. The new code might look like this:

```
foreach($commandes as $commande)
{
  $conn = $this->em->getConnection();
  $conn->beginTransaction();
  $conn->setAutoCommit(false);

  try {
    $tmp = $this->checkCommande($commande); // in this function there is multiple relationship created and pushed 

    if ($tmp) {
        $result = $tmp['result'];
        if ('OK' === $result) {
            $commande->setCompleted(true);
            $this->em->flush();
        }
    }

    $conn->commit(); // outside this line 
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    $conn->rollBack();
    throw $e;
  }
}
```

Comment: but in the function checkCommande() there is some entities persist and flush and I don't like commit  it if the result is not OK, So I wanna commit only if result  == 'OK'